# How to create footprint from IC diagram when no recommended layout is given?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, footprint

I'm a student trying to create a library part in Altium for an Analog Devices AD8232. Most IC datasheets give a recommended footprint to use, but [the AD8232 datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8232.pdf) only shows the IC itself:

[image]

I have been searching, but have been unable to find a recommended layout for this footprint.

If you were designing the footprint for this device, how would you determine the pad sizes to use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Method #1:

Tools->IPC Footprint Wizard->QFN and go from there.

This wizard is based on  IPC-7351 standard, the main standard for footprint creation. The standard is not straightforward if you want to calculate the footprint dimension by your own so it´s highly recommended to use the wizard.

---

Method #2:

Refer to [AN-772](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-772.pdf). **A Design and Manufacturing Guide for the Lead Frame Chip Scale Package (LFCSP)**